# Launching multiple processes of shell

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to use python to launch a command in multiple seperate instances of terminal simultaneously. What is the best way to do this? Right now I am trying to use the subprocess module with popen which works for one command but not multiple.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here is what I am doing:

```
from subprocess import*

Popen('ant -Dport='+str(5555)+ ' -Dhost='+GetIP()+ ' -DhubURL=http://192.168.1.113:4444 -Denvironment=*firefox launch-remote-control $HOME/selenium-grid-1.0.8', shell=True)
```

The problem for me is this launches a java process in the terminal which I want to have keep running indefinatley. Secondly, I want to run a similar command multiple times in multiple different processes.

Comment: This should also work for multiple, show your code.

Comment: You may need to use `Popen` to open terminal, like gnome-terminal, and use flags to send it the command you want to run.  The only problem with this is I cannot figure out how to make the terminal 'stay open' once it has finished the assigned command.

Comment: why should it stay open?

Comment: I'm using this to launch a selenium remote control- its a listener that needs to stay open for instructions from a host PC

Comment: In which case we should be okay, since the listener will not terminate until it is time for the window to go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should stay open as long as the process is running. If you want to launch multiple simultanously, just wrap it in a [thread](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#module-threading)

untested code, but you should get the general idea:

```
class PopenThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.port=port

    def run(self):
        Popen('ant -Dport='+str(self.port)+ ' -Dhost='+GetIP()+ 
                ' -DhubURL=http://192.168.1.113:4444' 
                ' -Denvironment=*firefox launch-remote-control'
                ' $HOME/selenium-grid-1.0.8', shell=True)

if '__main__'==__name__:
    PopenThread(5555).start()
    PopenThread(5556).start()
    PopenThread(5557).start()
```

EDIT: The double-fork method described down here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3765162/450517 by Mike would be the proper way to launch a daemon, i.e. a long-running process which won't communicate per stdio.

Comment: Using threads is pointless here. `Popen` doesn't block , so you'd get the same result just running `Popen` 3 times in the main thread. The problem is that the main program doesn't wait for any of the processes to terminate and so (on linux at least) leaves zombie programs laying around.

Comment: It's not clear from the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) that it woudn't block, and a thread won't hurt in this case. Also, those shouldn't be zombies, but run until done and then terminate, independently from the launching process.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer I can come up with is to have Python use `Popen` to launch a shell script similar to:

```
gnome-terminal --window -e 'ant -Dport=5555 -Dhost=$IP1 -DhubURL=http://192.168.1.113:4444 -Denvironment=*firefox launch-remote-control $HOME/selenium-grid-1.0.8' &
disown
gnome-terminal --window -e 'ant -Dport=5555 -Dhost=$IP2 -DhubURL=http://192.168.1.113:4444 -Denvironment=*firefox launch-remote-control $HOME/selenium-grid-1.0.8' &
disown
# etc. ...
```

There's a fully-Python way to do this, but it's ugly, only works on Unix-like OSes, and I don't have time to write the code out.  Basically, `subprocess.Popen` doesn't support it because it assumes you want to either wait for the subprocess to finish, interact with the subprocess, or monitor the subprocess.  It doesn't support the "just launch it and don't bother me with it ever again" case.

The way that's done in Unix-like OSes is to:

- Use `fork` to spawn a subprocess
- Have that subprocess `fork` a subprocess of its own
- Have the grandchild process redirect I/O to `/dev/null` and then use one of the `exec` functions to launch the process you really want to start (might be able to use `Popen` for this part)
- The child process exits.
- Now there's no link between the grandparent and grandchild, so if the grandchild terminates you don't get a `SIGCHLD` signal, and if the grandparent terminates it doesn't kill all the grandchildren.

I might be off in the details, but that's the gist.  Backgrounding (`&`) and `disown`ing in `bash` are supposed to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: nice to see the double-fork method described here

Answer (score 0):

Here is a poor version of a blocking queue.  You can fancify it with collections.deque or the like, or go even fancier with Twisted deferreds, or what not.  Crummy parts include:

- blocking
- kill signals might not propagate down

season to taste!

```
import logging
basicConfig = dict(level=logging.INFO, format='%(process)s %(asctime)s %(lineno)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
logging.basicConfig(**basicConfig)
logger = logging.getLogger({"__main__":None}.get(__name__, __name__))

import subprocess

def wait_all(list_of_Popens,sleep_time):
    """ blocking wait for all jobs to return.

    Args:
        list_of_Popens. list of possibly opened jobs

    Returns:
        list_of_Popens. list of possibly opened jobs

    Side Effect:
        block until all jobs complete.
    """
    jobs = list_of_Popens
    while None in [j.returncode for j in jobs]:
        for j in jobs:  j.poll()
        logger.info("not all jobs complete, sleeping for %i", last_sleep)
        time.sleep(sleep_time)  

    return jobs


jobs = [subprocess.Popen('sleep 1'.split()) for x in range(10)]
jobs = wait_all(jobs)
```